# GKE Container is taking more memory than allocated to it

Tags: docker, containers, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a GKE Cluster with multiple services/containers running on it. My Containers has requests and limits as 512Mi and 512Mi. But I could see its usage exceeds more than 700Mi (in Stackdriver and Workloads). This has been happening for a while. Can anyone suggest what could be the possible issue and how can we fix that?

Comment: With resource limits configured, this should not be possible, can you post your YAML file for the pod (deployment) in question as well as a screenshot showing the stackdriver chart